# Execute PHP code based on Javascript conditional

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not sure if what I wanna do will make any sense to you but here you go.
I'm trying to execute  into if / else. Here is an example of what I wanna do.

```
<?php
if //Here I would like to execute <script></script> 
{
// Then here execute some php code
}
else
{
//do nothing
}
?>
```

I don't know if such thing is possible.

Comment: you cant mix php and javascript.  php is executed before the visitor gets the html document and javascript is executed after they visitor gets the html document.

Comment: You can do so by evaluate the expression on the client side and send the result to the PHP server...

Comment: From what I gather, OP wants to do a conditional in javascript and execute PHP code. It of course isn't possible without AJAX or similar.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot execute PHP code with JS in the way you're suggesting. PHP is compiled and served on your server, then sent down the wire. This is the idea behind "front-end" and "back-end" components to a website.

You can, however, make requests to your server with JS (google "AJAX") that can execute any type of back-end language you'd like. Then, when your back-end responds, you can tell JS to change the DOM, or do whatever you'd like it to.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

One example of doing this using AJAX is the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='yourotherfile.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (functionFromOtherFile()) {
    $.get('somephpfile.php', function(data) {
         $("#output").text(data);
    }
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: "somethingelse.php",
        context: $("#output")
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Request completed.");
    });
}
</script>
```

In ["prototype"](http://prototypejs.org/), it would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Ajax.Request('somephpfile.php', 
{ 
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(data) {
      // do something with data.responseText
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What Arjan is bluntly trying to explain is that `condition` here would be the result of a JavaScript computation, which would then decide whether a block of PHP is executed or not

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is have <script></script> as my condition

Comment: Edited my answer. Not sure if it's what you want.

Comment: As far as I can understand here the condition isnt a JS right? Or is it my JS in simephpfile.php and then got to execute my phpcode with data.responseText?
Thanks again

Comment: AJAX is used to execute the php code in question... you would have a file, say `index.php` that has some javascript code with the condition you want. You would have a separate file, say `somefile.php` that contains the php logic to execute based on a condition.

Comment: Yes I can understand that now, but how about if my condition is a JS. That's the very problem. thx

Comment: Yes, above the condition *is* JavaScript, @Monica. Alternatively, consider if the PHP actually changes something (like in a database). If it does not change anything, then maybe you can actually *always* output its result, and only use JavaScript to actually show or hide it. Like `<?php if(...){ echo "Hello world" } ?>` could maybe be written as `<script>if(condition){ document.write('<?php echo "Hello world" ?>'); }</script>`.

Comment: @Arjan I may sound dumb by saying that, but I can't understand how to write my <script></script) into the if(condition)

Comment: Are you saying that you have an external JS file that contains your conditional?

Comment: Yes it is an external JS... but not an external file. Example : <script type="text/javascript".......></script> Sorry I should have been more specific

Comment: Simply include the file before the script block that has the AJAX calls, like so `<script type='text/javascript' src='otherfile.js'></script>`.

Comment: @Monica, see an example [here](http://codepad.org/9NPnx1CK). But note that in that case the PHP code is ALWAYS executed, even if the JavaScript condition is false (which would then not DISPLAY the PHP result).

Answer (score 0):

From you comments I would say there might be a bit of a misunderstanding, how Javascript and PHP work or how they interact.

It's like a pizza delivery service called PHP: You can order a pizza with ham on it, but as soon the delivery boy arrives at your door, it's to late to order pineapple on it. You could do some changes to the pizza at your home like eating it, but there will be no pineapple. Basically your original post would be something like "tell the delivery boy to eat the pizza", or to say it in another way - it won't work.

You could order a new pizza (this would be my example), or employ another delivery guy to just send you your pineapple slices (this would be the AJAX approach).

You don't have to use AJAX. You might want to try this (index.php) and check if that behaviour is useful to you.

This example features:

- evaluation of a condition on client side
- basic DOM manipulation
- usage of a hidden field to transmit data to the server backend
- evaluation of the transmitted data on server side
- invalid HTML markup and other usages of non best practices

[...]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple JavaScript Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>This is some test</h2>
  <form action="index.php" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="condition" />
      <input type="submit" value="Do something" />
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        if ($_GET["condition"]!="blueconditionistrue"){
    ?>
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    <?php
        } else { echo "alert('That blue was awful, I fixed it for you');"; }
    ?>

    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 255)"){
        document.forms[0].condition.value = "blueconditionistrue";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes possible.

```
<?php if(true):?>
<script>
//js  goes here
</script>
<?php else:?>
//other
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: Nope, the question is about JavaScript in the `if(...)` part.